# Работа побитового оператора ~(тильда)

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, мне встретился код, не могу понять использование побитового оператора ~ в проверке на наличие подстроки в строке.

```js
/*Создайте функцию addClass(obj, name), 
которая добавляет в список класс name, но только если его там еще нет*/
function addClass(obj, name) {
  var classes = (obj.className) ? obj.className.split(' ') : [];
  if (~obj.className.indexOf(name) !== -1) classes.push(name);
  obj.className = classes.join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Работу оператора тильда `~` можно описать формулой

```
-(N + 1)
```

где N - число перед тильдой.

Поэтому, например `var a = ~15; console.log(a);` выдаст -16

В вашем случае получается, что в результате `indexOf` может вернуться число или -1.  С помощью тильды это преобразуется в -1 или в `-(N + 1)` соответственно. Ну а далее будет сравниваться (точнее проверяться на неравенство минус единице), что выдаст true или false ну и соответственно сработает условный оператор или нет

Вообще условный оператор с `indexOf` можно было бы заменить на

```
if (~obj.className.indexOf(name))
```

Comment: Тильда замечательно подходит чтобы наводить на коллег ужас своим ниндзюцу конструкциями вроде return !!~obj.className.indexOf(name); , с одной стороны вроде все понятно, с другой стороны не всякий прочитает)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму но ведь при `!!` тильда не нужна. там и без неё приведется к булевой, поэтому в данном случае это избыточно

Comment: Приведется да не то по смыслу. !!-1 - true. А мы хотим false если не нашлось) То есть obj.className.indexOf(name) != -1 простыми словами