# JavaScript Двойное отрицание(!!) и побитовый оператор Тильда (~)

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JavaScript. Задачка из учебника:
Напишите функцию checkSpam(str), которая возвращает true, если строка str содержит „html“ или „css“, а иначе false.
Функция должна быть нечувствительна к регистру:

Ответ из учебника:

```js
function checkSpam(str) {
  var lowerStr = str.toLowerCase();

  return !!(~lowerStr.indexOf('html') || ~lowerStr.indexOf('css'));
}

alert( checkSpam('hTml now') );
alert( checkSpam('free cSs') );
alert( checkSpam("more java") );
```

**Вопросы:**

1. Меня путает наличие сразу **!!** и **~**
   Как читается строка **return**? "Если не найдено, то вернуть ..."
   первый знак **!** = **Не**, и приводим к логическому типу; дальше непонятки из-за **~** и второго отрицания.
2. Вот мой вариант, он мне кажется понятнее:

```js
function checkSpam(str) {
 var lowerStr = str.toLowerCase();
 return (lowerStr.indexOf('html') != -1 || lowerStr.indexOf('css') != -1);
}
alert( checkSpam('hTml now') );
alert( checkSpam('free cSs') );
alert( checkSpam("more java") );
```

Есть ли в данных вариантах разница и какой вид более предпочтительный?

Comment: И тот и ваш. В чём собственно проблема? Оба варианты чистые, работают одинаково..

Comment: Первый вопрос прочитайте. Здесь два вопроса.

Comment: О, его та я и пропустил. Сейчас вам кто-то ответит. А если нет, то я освобожусь и отвечу :)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/615521/191482

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Мне это известно, читайте внимательнее вопрос .Сложность для меня, что здесь еще двойное отрицание.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov перевод в булев тип...

Comment: Вот ещё по теме: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/188946

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Знак `!` обозначает `не`.

Если вы напишите `return (~lowerStr.indexOf('html') || ~lowerStr.indexOf('css'))`, то оно просто выведет положение слов.
Если вы введёте `return !(~lowerStr.indexOf('html') || ~lowerStr.indexOf('css'))`, но оно выведет `true/false`, при том, что `false` выведется, если слово было найдено
А когда вы вводите два `!!`, то оно выведет `true`, там где было `false` и наоборот

Знак `~` возвращает значение `-(число + 1)`.
Т.е. в вашем случае, если положение равно `-1`, то она выводит `0` и при этом в условии выводится `false`, а если другое любое число, то это `true`

Comment: Пример разберем `alert( checkSpam('free cSs') );`  После `~lowerStr.indexOf('css')` получаем **-6** = `true`, поскольку нам в задаче нужно true или false мы переводим в булево первым знаком отрицания, но вместе с тем, `true` становится `false` и для этого нужен второй знак отрицания и мы вновь меняем `false` на `true`. Все верно? Кажется я просто ваши слова повторил немного по-другому.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov, нет. Если без `~`, то оно выведет `-1`, как `true`, а если предложение будет начинаться с нужного слова, то оно покажет `0` и оно выведет `false`. Но да, если мы получим положение `-6`, то оно получит `true`, потом переведёт его в `false` и потом обратно в `true`

Comment: Вот мой пример `function checkSpam(str) {
  var lowerStr = str.toLowerCase();

  return (~lowerStr.indexOf('html') || ~lowerStr.indexOf('css'));
}
alert( checkSpam('free cSs') );`  минус шесть выдает

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov, и что? Значит слово начинается с положения `5`

Comment: Значит вы или свой комментарий раньше изменили и там не было про -6, или я просмотрел. **Еще вопрос:** если **indexOf** не находит подстроку, то цепочка получается такая: получаем `false` после первого `!` получаем `true`, после второго `!` вновь `false` и он идет в **alert**. Все верно?

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov, если строка не найдена, то оно показывает `-1`, тильда переводит это в `0`, первый знак `!` выводит `true`, а второй знак `!` выводит `false`

Answer (score 6):

Вы столкнулись с "магией операторов". В данном случае операторы применяются для следующего:

1. Оператор `~` возвращает 0 для -1 и не 0 для всего остального. Поэтому в булевом контексте оператор `~` делает *почти* то же самое, что и сравнение `!= -1`.
2. Оператор `!!` (на самом деле это два оператора), который вы правильно назвали двойным отрицанием, преобразует любое значение в булево. Этот оператор нужен только потому что оператор `~` возвращает число, если бы там было сравнение - то и двойное отрицание бы не понадобилось.

Таким образом, вы совершенно правильно написали `return (lowerStr.indexOf('html') != -1 || lowerStr.indexOf('css') != -1);`. Ваш вариант делает в точности то же самое, что и строка из учебника, только написан понятнее.

Можно даже убрать скобки:

```
return lowerStr.indexOf('html') != -1 || lowerStr.indexOf('css') != -1;
```

Именно так и надо писать если ваш код будет читать кто-то, кроме вас самих. Если же вы пишите так называемый "write-only" код - иногда имеет смысл использовать "магические" сокращения, коли это ускоряет его написание.

Answer (score 0):

Не только, но и ~~undefined === 0

```
function add (a, b) {
  var res = '', c = 0
  a = a.split('')
  b = b.split('')
  while (a.length || b.length || c) {
    c += ~~a.pop() + ~~b.pop()
    res = c % 10 + res
    c = c > 9
  }
  return res
}
```

add('63829983432984289347293874', '90938498237058927340892374089')

Здесь две тильды заменяет (parseInt(a.pop()) || 0). Круто, на мой взгляд.